# Javascript to make background image clickable?

Tags: javascript, image, background, clickable

I can't use a div because the CMS I am using won't allow html into the theme style (it's using a weird structure in its coding) and the only thing that I found that has worked is javascript but I don't know what javascript code will enable a clickable background image.

Any ideas?

```
<meta name="description" content="description here"> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    document.backgroundImage = "url('http://mydomain.com/image.jpg')";
    function callback() { 
        location.href = "http://mylink.com";
    } 
    document.addEventListener("click", callback, false);
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> //google analytics code </script>
```

Comment: What is that CMS you are using?

Comment: @agentmilindu - My boss is using questions2answers from www.question2answer.org/ to make a Q&A site.

Comment: Hmm I checked that site, I checked the demo, I logged in as the admin, I checked the layout tab, I could add,  Custom HTML at top of every page, Custom HTML at bottom of every page, Custom HTML in <HEAD> section of every page, Custom content in home page instead of Q&A, Show a logo image in the page header, Include <META> description for home page and Custom HTML in sidebar box on every page. What are you going to do when someone cklicked your bg-Image? What are you really trying to do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is the background of *something* right? This *something* has to receive the click event handler.

cheers.

edit: adding example:

Hypothesis:

```
o.id = "OhMyCuteness";
o.style.backgroundImage = "url('...')";
```

then:

```
o.addEventListener("click", callback, false);
```

and:

```
function callback(clickEvent) {
    alert("They clicked meeeee buhuhuhu: " + clickEvent.target.id);
}
```

Edit2: in the case your document has a background this is exactly the same, use the document instead of the element "o" as a target for `addEventListener`.

Comment: This is correct. But to clarify: Whatever the element this background image is the background of, is what you need to make clickable.

Comment: @Sebas - So where would I put the background image link at and the actual url link to make it clickable?

Comment: the background image is setup through the css property "backgroundImage": `.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://...')";`

Comment: @Sebas - so what would the javascript and css look like in a real-case scenario when it's all put together? Trying to figure out where to put what.

Comment: what is the object receiving the background?

Comment: @Sebas - This is just an example: background image = folder/myimage.jpg   link = www.othersite.com   not sure what you mean by receiving but I'm putting the code into the theme file in between a meta tag and another javascript code (google analytics).

Comment: @Sebas - 


<meta name="description" content="description here">

<script type="text/javascript">

o.id = "http://link here";
o.style.background = "url(http://image.jpg)";

o.addEventListener("click", callback, false);

function callback(clickEvent) {
    alert("They clicked meeeee buhuhuhu: " + clickEvent.target.id);
}

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//google analytics code
</script>

Comment: I'm not sure to get it: 2 questions, answer both please: 1/ is the image on YOUR pc, or at the server? 2/ do you want it as a background of the page or of an element in particular?

Comment: @Sebas - 1. on the server 2. I want is as a background of the page but  I want it to be clickable so it should be a clickable image set in the background.  Problem is I can't do it in html cuz the CMS won't let me.

Comment: I edited your code in the question. Change the image url to be the url on your server, and the link you want to go to within the callback

Comment: @Sebas - not working :( I don't have the image url set in the body css property.  The only thing that is showing in the background is a background color, which is black, which is the background color I set in the body css property.

Comment: you can't set a background color at the same time than a background image i think. And why don't you add this image link in the css?

Comment: @Sebas - works now but how to make it so that the image looks clickable? The cursor never changes when I hover over the image.  I changed the body css so that it has the image but no background color.

Comment: well this is your background, stop saying "the image". You are not making the image clickable, you are making your document clickable. I guess you could use `document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';`

Comment: @Sebas - pointer didn't change but regardleess, it makes me happy. Thanks!

Comment: this is really tricky to change the pointer of an element, sometimes we have to change the pointer of all overlapping elements... but i think in your case it should work, delve a little bit and you'll find it ;)